# i have code like this for auto complete feature but am not able fetch the data from the data base.kindly help me out

Tags: javascript, php, html

My aim is to fetch location from the database once user start entering in the input tetc field
i have done all the coding properly but the also am not able to fetch the data from the database.

```
<!--My java script code-->
$(function() {
$( "#LocationName" ).autocomplete({
source: 'search.php'
});
});

<!--My Search.php code-->
<?php
include('dbConnect.php');

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT LocationName,From arealistmain WHERE LocationName LIKE ?");
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $array[] = array (

            'value' => $row['LocationName'].'',

        );
    }
    //RETURN JSON ARRAY
    echo json_encode ($array);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your query to below code

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT LocationName From arealistmain WHERE LocationName LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'");
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row['LocationName'];
}
```

Comment: Hi sachin thanks for the answer.but its not working.

Comment: I have updated my code can try once with updated code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `mysql_*` functions as they were deprecated in `PHP 5.5` and removed in `PHP 7` instead use `mysqli_*` functions.

Second thing you should always sanitize user input don't just do `$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];` read more about [this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Then your SQL query should read

```
$query = "SELECT LocationName From arealistmain WHERE LocationName LIKE '%$searchTerm%';";
```

The comma before `FROM` removed and the `$searchTerm` is enclosed in two percentage signs to match all